# How to use Bootstrap datepicker with Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I know there have been similar questions answered on this site, but Meteor has changed a lot in the last year, and I haven't found any solutions that work for me. I'm running Meteor 0.6.6.3.

I have a simple template:

```
<template name="add_part">
  <form id="part_form">
    <input class="datepicker" id="date-id" name="date">
  </form>
</template>
```

And I have the following in my client.js:

```
Template.add_part.rendered = function() {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker();
}
```

I get the following errors in my console:

```
Exception from Deps afterFlush function: Template.add_part.rendered@http://localhost:3000/client/client.js?091c09a531c04d4a8f09bbc8066245a490dec458:65
Template.__define__/partial/html</html<.rendered@http://localhost:3000/packages/templating.js?5944cd5e16b26fbf83959a0fe92d7754029a624d:181
scheduleOnscreenSetup/</<@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:443
_.forEach@http://localhost:3000/packages/underscore.js?13ab483e8a3c795d9991577e65e811cd0b827997:130
scheduleOnscreenSetup/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab:441
.flush@http://localhost:3000/packages/deps.js?5ac28feec1f3e0539889ecde598dd9d01e408b41:265
```

Comment: I use the jquery ui datepicker exactly the way you have it on the same Meteor version, so I'm not sure what's up. Are you using a package or how did you add the datepicker library to Meteor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

landland was right. I forgot to include jquery-ui.js  I was thinking this was included in Bootstrap by default.  At least this serves as a very clear and simple example of how to do this with Meteor.